# mysql сильно грузит процессор

Tags: mysql, cpu

Всем добрый день!
Прошу помощи, совета, подсказки в моей проблеме.

Имеем выделенный сервер 2х Xeon E5-2670, 64Gb RAM, 240Gb SSD.
На сервере расположен единственный проект среднего уровня. В проекте присутствует база данных из 3 таблиц.
Загруженность MySQL:

root@d:/var/log/mysql# mysqladmin status
Uptime: 5562  Threads: 132  Questions: 581856  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 359  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 322  Queries per second avg: 104.612

К таблицам выполняется достаточно большое количество запросов SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT.

Первая таблица - SELECT и UPDATE запросы, редко INSERT. Таблица InnoDB, примерно 12000 записей.

Вторая таблица основная, "рабочая", в ней постоянно присутствует ~500 000 записей. INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT присутствует в полном объеме, в час пик порядка 300-400 запросов в секунду именно к этой таблице. MyISAM.

Третья таблица MyISAM, самая "тяжелая" - порядка 150 миллионов записей. Запросы к ней не частые, это INSERT (по 500-1000 строк) и SELECT (полнотекстовый). Ключи на месте, запросы выполняются быстро.

Расставлены ключи на основные поля, запросы выполняются достаточно быстро, slow-запросы в логах отсутствуют.

На сервере сайт расположен всего неделю, но уже сейчас в часы активности наблюдаются серьезные "провалы" в работе сайта. MySQL сильно грузит процессор, в htop'е периодически появляется [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом Load average в пределах нормы и в целом сервер работает стабильно.

Ищу причины происходящего.

Что делал:
-расставлял дополнительные ключи, сейчас практически все поля по которым -выполняются запросы являются ключами.
- ковырялся в конфигурации mysql. Признаюсь честно, не эксперт в этом вопросе - поэтому ничего конкретного тут не сделано и пользы от этого не замечено

Подозреваю - нужно что то менять в конфиге mysql
Возможно - переводить рабочую таблицу в InnoDB.

В интернете попадаются похожие проблемы, но решения найти не удалось..
Прошу помощи, друзья, в решении моей проблемы.

Comment: последий раз когда я видел подобную проблему оказалось, что были скрипты, которые постоянно перечитывали мелкими запросами одно и то же, множество раз в секунду. Вылечилось исправлением ошибки в тех скриптах. Выявлялось с помощью `show full porocesslist` на глазок, с целью найти наиболее частые запросы, которые попадаются в выполняемом состоянии.

Comment: "_сейчас практически все поля по которым -выполняются запросы являются ключами_" - наличие ключей во первых серьезно замедляет вставку, во вторых часто портит планы выполнения, MySQL при наличии не правильного ключа может пойти по нему, что будет значительно медленнее, чем если бы он решил идти по другому. Фактически после принятия решения о создании нового ключа надо перепроверять все старые запросы, которые хоть каким то боком могут захотеть его использовать

Comment: Примерно такое у меня и происходит - постоянно пересчитываются мелкие count(*) и т.д., этого не избежать - пользователи просматривают статистику постоянно обновляющуюся.

Comment: Основное дополнение! На сайте постоянно запускаются "долгоиграющие" скрипты, выполнение которых может занимать от 10 минут до часа и более.. Каждый скрипт в начале открывает соединение с mysql, и взаимодействует с ней в процессе. Т.е. соединение может быть открытым до часа, при этом действия выполняются раз в 2-3 секунды. Может в этом корень "зла"?

Comment: нет, это как раз хорошо. открытие соединения то же отнимает время и у открывающего и у MySQL. У нас например вообще используется полный fastcgi, обработчики web-запросов всегда подгружены в памяти и держат соединения с БД постоянно, сутками. И уж с этим точно никаких проблем, только выигрыш. Все мелкие справочники при этом вообще у себя в памяти держат и обновляют только когда те поменялись, о чем узнают из redis. Кстати, мелкие count() я бы то же в redis держал, уже готовые, только надо решить как обновлять

Comment: Разрешите slowlog — увидите тяжёлые запросы. Поглядите в `show full processlist` — увидите частые запросы. Отдайте мускулю побольше памяти под буфера — гигов 48 я бы не постеснялся, только убедитесь, что разрешён O_DIRECT, чтобы не было двойной буферизации. И да, перевод всего в InnoDB выглядит хорошим вариантом, хотя бы для того, чтобы не тюнить два разных движка по памяти.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Нагрузка процессоров под 200% mysql говорит о том, что все обрабатываемые данные уже в памяти. Интенсивный ввод-вывод опустил бы очень сильно cpu. И `Slow queries: 0` подсказывает, что в slowlog ничего не будет

Comment: @Mike согласен насчёт ввода-вывода, даже с поправкой на SSD, но вряд ли он может подолгу болтаться в топе без slow queries. Чем-то же занимается, и это не похоже на пачки мелких запросов. Возможно, slowlog сильно закручен, и надо ему время уменьшить. И от рекомендации отдать ему память не отказываюсь. Очевидно, что приложение лучше управляет своими app-specific данными, чем когда запрашивает их из буферов OS — а здесь это очевидно: RES 1G (это default) при VIRT под тридцать гигов. При оптимальной настройке _размера буферов БД_ под текущие нужды они должны быть почти равны.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Да, с памятью я то же с вами согласен. только у меня в голове что то не укладывается с теми цифрами. буфера ОС вообще не учитываются в размере процесса. Я совершенно не понимаю откуда там 26Г виртуальной взялось, при том что swap 0. такая картина бывает только при использовании файлов отраженных на память (mmap). Если mysql это использует то он использует ту же память, что и дисковые буфера ОС. хотя ранее я не слышал, что бы он так делал.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Еще настораживает два отдельных процесса mysql жрущих процессор, обычно он один. Такое ощущение, что второй - отвечает за сессии пользователей, а его нагрузка тогда означает что mysql занят передачей большого объема данных клиенту.

Comment: @Mike IMHO он не может _так_ жрать время передачей данных, притом что пыхи не особо трудятся. Насчёт буферов — ну, да, вопрос спорный. В любом случае, надо смотреть processlist, чтобы понять, чем он там в основном в эти моменты занят.